# creating a collection by querying the db with conditions

Tags: grails

I'm attempting to query a PerformanceReview table, which `belongsTo` a PerformanceReviewStatus, that will return performance reviews with a status of `new` or `open`. I figured out how to get all the performance reviews that have a status of new but how would i find all with a status of either new or open?

```
def newStatus = PerformanceReviewStatus.findByName('New')
def openStatus = PerformanceReviewStatus.findByName('open')
def query = PerformanceReview.findAllByPerformanceReviewStatus(newStatus)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple HQL would look something like:

```
def performanceReviews = 
   PerformanceReview.executeQuery("select pr from PerformanceReview as pr \
                                   inner join pr.performanceReviewStatus as prs \
                                   where prs.name in (:name)", 
                                   [name: ['New', 'Open']])
```

*Disclaimer*:- Just double check to use left join in case you are not getting expected result.

In case you want to stick to dynamic finders, try using inList

```
def query = 
 PerformanceReview.findAllByPerformanceReviewStatusInList([newStatus,openStatus])
```